# Better way to assert data type of all values in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, unit-testing, dictionary, types, assertion

I'm building a unit test that asserts/checks if all values in a dictionary has the same data type: `float`.

Python version 3.7.4

Suppose I have four different dictionaries as such:

```
dictionary1: dict = {
    "key 1": 1.0,
}

dictionary2: dict = {
    "key 1": "1.0",
}

dictionary3: dict = {
    "key 1": 1.0,
    "key 2": 2.0,
    "key 3": 3.0
}

dictionary4: dict = {
    "key 1": "1",
    "key 2": "2",
    "key 3": 3
}
```

And a unit test case as such:

```
class AssertTypeUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_value_types(self):
        dictionary: dict = dictionary
        self.assertTrue(len(list(map(type, (dictionary[key] for key in dictionary)))) is 1 and
                            list(map(type, (dictionary[key] for key in dictionary)))[0] is float)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The expected result would be that it throws an `AssertionError` if there's one value in the dictionary that is not `float`, i.e. it would do that for `dictionary2` but not for `dictionary1`.

Now while the test **does work for 1 key-value pair**, how would I do that for multiple key-value pair in cases such as `dictionary3` and `dictionary4` without having to add another for loop?

i.e.

```
for type in list(map(type, (dictionary[key] for key in dictionary))):
    self.assertTrue(type is float)
```

Thanks!

Comment: maybe use `assertIsInstance` instead of checking for the boolean values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the types of the items to a set and assert that it is equal to a set of `float`:

```
self.assertSetEqual(set(map(type, dictionary.values())), {float})
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's break the assert you wrote to understand what it is actually doing.

```py
self.assertTrue(
    len(list(map(type, (dictionary[key] for key in dictionary)))) is 1  #
    and  #
    list(map(type, (dictionary[key] for key in dictionary)))[0] is float
)
```

You have two conditions there that must be true for the assert to pass. The first one is

```py
len(list(map(type, (dictionary[key] for key in dictionary)))) is 1
```

This creates a list with the type of each value in the dictionary, computes its length and check that it is one. Well, this list will always have the same number of elements that you dictionary has. Checking that this length is equal to one has nothing to do with what you are asking.

The second condition is

```py
list(map(type, (dictionary[key] for key in dictionary)))[0] is float
```

This will create a list with the type of each value in the dictionary as before, then check that the first element of this list is float. That does not necessarey means all elements in the original dictionary are float.

Using what you already wrote, the easy way to check is get the list of types, take the first element and then check that all elements are equal to the first element.

```py
l = list(map(type, (dictionary[key] for key in dictionary)))
for t in l: 
    self.assertTrue(t==l[0])
```

But there are many ways to do the test. You can also convert this list into a set and check that its length is equal to one (since set will only keep unique values)

```
self.assertTrue(len(set(l)) == 1)
# or self.assertEqual(len(set(l)), 1)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for breaking things down! I `(len(list(map(type, (dictionary[key] for key in dictionary)))) is 1 and list(map(type, (dictionary[key] for key in dictionary)))[0] is float)` works in my project since the dictionary **only** contains 1 key-value pair. Seems I forgot to test the example case.

Comment: It is always a good idea to break things down into simpler pieces for checking, even if you think the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but wanted to solve it in a more general fashion using the [typing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/typing.html) module of the python standard library. It uses the package [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/), which seems like a reasonable dependency. Here is my approach.

```py
import unittest
import typing
import pydantic

def check_type(obj, expected_type):

    class Model(pydantic.BaseModel):
        data: expected_type

    # convert ValidationError to TypeError if the obj does not match the expected type
    try:
        Model(data=obj)
    except pydantic.ValidationError as ve:
        raise TypeError(str(ve.errors()))

    return True  # allow constructs like assert check_type(x, List[float])

class TestCase1(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_check_type(self):

        obj1 = [3, 4, 5]
        obj2 = [3, 4, "x"]

        check_type(obj1, typing.List[int]) # pass silently

        with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as cm:
            check_type(obj2, typing.List[int])

        obj3 = {
                "key 1": 1.0,
                "key 2": 2.0,
                "key 3": 3.0
                }

        check_type(obj3, typing.Dict[str, pydantic.StrictFloat])

        obj3["key 3"] = "3.0"

        with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as cm:
            check_type(obj3, typing.Dict[str, pydantic.StrictFloat])

        # note that this passes:
        check_type(obj3, typing.Dict[str, float])


        # allow for multiple types:
        check_type(obj3, typing.Dict[str, typing.Union[int, float, str]])
```